# Ignore capitalization when ordering dict using pprint?

Tags: python, dictionary, printing, pprint

So I have a dictionary, say:

```
myDict = {"145":1, "Kittens":2, "apples":1, "trees":2}
```

and using `pprint(myDict, ...)`, I get:

```
{'145': 1,
 'Kittens': 2,
 'apples': 1,
 'trees': 2}
```

Instead, I'd like to ignore the capital K's apparent order priority and get:

```
{'145': 1,
 'apples': 1,
 'Kittens': 2,
 'trees': 2}
```

Do I have to use the PrettyPrinter module? Is there a hidden pprint argument? Or is there another solution entirely? My dict keys aren't any more complicated than this. Thanks.

Comment: You can not order a dictionary (only in some versions of Python-3.6). You should use an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Certainly. However, `pprint.pprint` orders the keys when you print a dict, as mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html)

Comment: And to the best of my knowledge has no provision for custom sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without imports, simple version:

```
def printdict(myDict):
    print('{')
    for a,b in sorted(myDict.items(),key = lambda tuple : tuple[0].lower()):
        print("'"+str(a)+"'"+" : "+str(b))
    print('}')
```

Improved version according to [PM 2Ring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4014959/pm-2ring) ( this will work for anything ):

```
def printdict(myDict):
    print('{')
    for a,b in sorted(myDict.items(),key = lambda t : t[0].lower()):
        print(' {!r}: {!r},'.format(a, b))
    print('}')
```

Comment: This worked rather nicely for my actual input. I haven't used too many one-line lambda statements, so I'm going to try and figure out what's going on here. Also have to figure out how to now write this to a new .txt file! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Read print() function documentation. It supports a ",file=open("file.txt","a")" argument. So you can use print() to print to a file instead of stdout.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `tuple` as a variable name, as that shadows the built-in `tuple` type. It won't hurt here, since it's just a local name in the lambda, but IMHO it's still a bit confusing. FWIW, I'd use `tup` or even just `t` in that situation.

Comment: Also, your inner `print` call can be improved. Currently, it won't work properly if `a` contains a quote (which hopefully will never happen, but still), and it will fail if `b` happens to be a string. Generally, you should let `print` or `format` do string conversions for you. Here's an improved version: `print(' {!r}: {!r},'.format(a, b))`. The `!r` say to use the object's `__repr__`, so strings will automatically get quoted properly.